# How do I get tab completion to work with 'rake'?

Tags: rails, auto-completion

When I try to use tab completion with `rake`, only files are suggested:

```
$ rails test-app | grep -v create; cd test-app
$ rake <TAB><TAB>
app/      db/       lib/      public/   README    test/     vendor/   
config/   doc/      log/      Rakefile  script/   tmp/
```

The package `rake-0.8.7-2` includes a Bash completion configuration file,

```
$ debsums -e rake
/etc/bash_completion.d/rake                                         OK
```

so I expect that pressing tab should suggest the tasks available to rake:

```
$ rake --tasks
(in ~/sandbox/test-app)
rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations       # Raises an error if there are pending migrations
rake db:charset                           # Retrieves the charset for the current environment's database
rake db:collation                         # Retrieves the collation for the current environment's database
rake db:create                            # Create the database defined in config/database.yml for the current RAIL...
rake db:create:all                        # Create all the local databases defined in config/database.yml
rake db:drop                              # Drops the database for the current RAILS_ENV
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

The problem persists after reinstalling rake and restarting my computer. My `~/.bashrc` contains:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

but completion for `rake` doesn't appear to be registered:

```
$ complete | grep rake
$
```

Explicitly running `. /etc/bash_completion` in the shell doesn't solve the problem, but running the following command does enable completion for `rake` temporarily:

```
$ grep complete /etc/bash_completion.d/rake
[ -n "${have:-}" ] && complete -F _rake $filenames rake
$ complete -F _rake rake
$ rake <TAB><TAB>
db:abort_if_pending_migrations       db:version                           rails:update
db:charset                           doc:app                              rails:update:application_controller
db:collation                         doc:clobber_app                      rails:update:configs
db:create                            doc:clobber_plugins                  rails:update:generate_dispatchers
db:create:all                        doc:clobber_rails                    rails:update:javascripts
db:drop                              doc:guides                           rails:update:scripts
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tab completions are loaded when opening a shell. When installing an application, you need either to re-open your shell or run the next command to load the new bash completions:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

Looks like it's [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rake/+bug/828183) in `rake`. `[ -n "${have:-}" ]` checks if a variable named `$have` is set. This won't work if the previous have call failed. Replace it by `have rake`:

```
have rake && complete -F _rake $filenames rake
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be the problem this time. I've updated my question with more information.

Comment: Updated upon further investigation.